# How do I "reset" a function in C++?

Tags: c++14

```
    #include <iostream>

double getUserInput()
{
    std::cout << "Input a number: ";
    double value;
    std::cin >> value;
    return value;
}

int getMathOp()
{
    std::cout << "Input one of the following math operators: +, -, * or / : ";
    char op;
    std::cin >> op;
    return op;
}

int printReuslt(double x, char op, double y)
{
    if (op == '+')
        std::cout << x << " + " << y << " is " << x + y << '\n';
    else if (op == '-')
        std::cout << x << " - " << y << " is " << x - y << '\n';
    else if (op == '*')
        std::cout << x << " * " << y << " is " << x * y << '\n';
    else if (op == '/')
        std::cout << x << " / " << y << " is " << x / y << '\n';
    else 
        std::cout << op << " is not a valid operator. An error has occurred";
}

int main()
{
    double x = getUserInput();
    double y = getUserInput();

    char op = getMathOp();

    printReuslt(x, op, y);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm building a very simple calculator.

1. getUserInput() - Takes a value (a number) from the user and
   stores it as a double variable called 'value'
2. getMathOp() - Takes a value (a mathematical operator: +, -, * or
   /) from the user and stores it as a char variable called 'op'
3. printResult() - Calculates the result
   for each instance of x op y (which are: x + y, x - y, x * y, x / y).
   It then prints that result.
4. main() - Pulls each function together in the correct sequence.

I want to add two additional pieces of functionality that do the following:

1. If the user inputs a value other than a double, the programme will
   output a message that tells the user "value is not a number" and
   will make the user enter a value that is a double so the programme
   can continue.
2. If the user inputs a mathematical operator that is
   not in the message "+, -, * or /", the programme will output a
   message that tells the user "operator is not a valid operator" and
   will make the user enter a specified operator so the programme can
   continue.

For the first piece of functionality, I've envisioned it by simply "resetting" the function to its first line - making the user go through the step of inputting in a number again.
I would achieve this by having an 'if' statement that takes the input value to be something that is not a double which would execute a message saying "value is not a number". The function will then reset to the first line and ignore the previous input.

For the second piece of functionality, I've made somewhat of a start by including an 'else' statement in 'printResult' that takes the input value to be something that is not specified as a math operator which executes a message "operator is not a valid operator. An error has occurred". Following this, the programme ends.
I want that message to output and then reset the 'printResult' function to its first line (ignoring previous input) rather than ending the programme after the message output.

My question is how  would I do what I am intending (resting a function to its first line, ignoring the previous input, so the user can input a new value) and what is the most optimal way to implement this functionality into my code?
Also, any improvements to the intended functionality I want to add would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are implementing a simple REPL (Read Eval Print Loop); your have the REP part started, add the L ;-) (in other words, read up on loops)

Answer (score 0):

Use some form of a **loop** with a sequence of operations like:

- read inputs
- validate inputs
- do-the-job but only if all-inputs-were-ok

Additionaly take care to ensure that after successful "do-the-job" the next run of the loop reads ALL inputs again, even if they were OK before the job, or else it will continue with stale inputs after the first succesful task.

i.e. something like

```
double x, y;
char op;

// make sure that first iteration will read everything
bool x_OK=false, y_OK=false, op_OK=false;

while(true)
{
    // only re-read parts that were broken
    // or, if you want to re-read ALL not just those broken, just remove IFs
    if(!x_OK) x = getX();
    if(!y_OK) y = getY();
    if(!op_OK) op = getOP();

    // ensure that we know what's broken
    x_OK = checkNumber(x);
    y_OK = checkNumber(y);
    op_OK= checkOp(op);

    if(!x_Ok) // error message..
    if(!y_Ok) // error message..
    if(!op_Ok) // error message..

    // ready to go?
    if( x_OK&&y_OK&&op_OK )
    {
       printReuslt(x, op, y);
       x_OK = y_OK = op_OK = false; // clear to force next iteration to read all
    }
    // else - nothing! loop will loop and will start again
    // but now with DIFFERENT states of x/y/op/OK variables
    // so next iteration of the loop will probably behave
    // in a different way to previous
}
```

This is of course absolutely naive sketch, no handling/clearing of CIN errors, etc. Few functions are also missing but you should get the idea from their names. Also, it's a good idea to add some smart quit condition instead of while-true.